# How to send file over local network from a windows machine to a linux machine?

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I am asked to send a text file from a computer from a windows machine to a linux machine,a raspberry pi model b  to be exact . Knowing that they are on the same local network, what are the steps to do in order to enable such a manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Try pscp:

Download and run putty installer: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html, then in your windows terminal type:

```
Program Files( x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe <path_to_file_to_be_copied> <user>@<ip_addres_of_your_raspberry>:<path>
```

Example:

```
pscp.exe C:\Users\SantaClaus\Desktop\someText.txt santaClaus@10.2.3.4:/home/santaClaus/
```